# How can i get access token for google drive rest api call?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I want to pass access token for get the list of files from google drive.

What I have done :

1. Register app to Google dev console.
2. I have client id based on OAuth 2.0

What i want to do :

1. Call `HttpCall` for `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files`
2. I want to set access token in header like this :

   `DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files");
   post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   post.addHeader("Authorization","Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");`
3. How can I get access token for Authorization by using `OAuth2.0` Client Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are making calls with scopes that are available in [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro) then that would be your best bet.

Otherwise you could use the Google Drive Java client library. In this instance you can use the GoogleAccountCredential for Auth, which will contain the access token, however you will not need to use it directly. See an example [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/android).

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [Drive for Android](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/) documentation.

That makes the whole job a hell lot simpler. For example

## Create a file:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);
    IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
            .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
            .setMimeType(new String[] { "text/plain", "text/html" })
            .build(getGoogleApiClient());
    try {
        startIntentSenderForResult(
                intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_OPENER, null, 0, 0, 0);
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
    }
}
```

## List files in a folder

To list all the files in a folder

```
/**
 * An activity that illustrates how to list files in a folder.
 */
public class ListFilesInFolderActivity extends BaseDemoActivity implements
        ResultCallback {

    private static DriveId sFolderId = DriveId.decodeFromString("DriveId:0B2EEtIjPUdX6MERsWlYxN3J6RU0");

    private ListView mResultsListView;
    private ResultsAdapter mResultsAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        super.onCreate(connectionHint);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listfiles);
        mResultsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewResults);
        mResultsAdapter = new ResultsAdapter(this);
        mResultsListView.setAdapter(mResultsAdapter);
        DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(getGoogleApiClient(), sFolderId);
        folder.listChildren(getGoogleApiClient()).setResultCallback(childrenRetrievedCallback);
    }

    ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult> childrenRetrievedCallback = new
            ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                showMessage("Problem while retrieving files");
                return;
            }
            mResultsAdapter.clear();
            mResultsAdapter.append(result.getMetadataBuffer());
            showMessage("Successfully listed files.");
        }
    }
}
```

## Query for a file

To query for a file say "HelloWorld.java":

```
Query query = new Query.Builder()
    .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "HelloWorld.java"))
    .build();
Drive.DriveApi.query(googleApiClient, query);
```

For more details on querying [please look at this part of documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/queries).